# REGEX - Remove Unwanted Text

Tags: regex, powershell, file

I have a list of Items example (files in a folder), each item in the list is in its own string.

in the example the X--Y-- Have incrementing Digits.

my program has the filenames in a list eg : **["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]**

*item 1:*
`"X1Y2 alehandro alex.txt"`

*item 2:*
`"X1Y3 james file of files.txt"`

so for each string i want to keep only the first Part the **"X1Y2"** parts for each file so I need to remove all the extra text on the filename.

I just want a regex expression on how to do this, I still do struggle with regex.

I need to pass this through a, replace with `""` algorithm,

(using microsoft powertoys-rename to do this..

Alternatives in powershell also welcome.

any advice would be appreciated

I Want output to be the following

["X1Y2.txt","X2Y3.txt","X4Y3.txt"]
with the unwanted extra text removed.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution using `re.sub` along with a list comprehension might be:

```py
files = ["X1Y2 alehandro alex.txt", "X1Y3 james file of files.txt"]
output = [re.sub(r'(\S+).*\.(\w+)$', r'\1.\2', f) for f in files]
print(output)  # ['X1Y2.txt', 'X1Y3.txt']
```

Comment: I guess with this [PowerToys Rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename#examples-of-regular-expressions) the replacement will be `$1.$2`

Comment: @Bobble Oops...I saw the regex tag, the _absence_ of any language, the list given, and assumed Python.  Guess I was wrong.